# Gridvew.RenderControl returns empty string

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to export a Gridview to excel. I bind the gridview to a collection and can see that it has 6 data rows but when i call the RenderControl it returns an empty string. Below is the code i am using

```
Gridview1.DataSource = data;
Gridview1.DataBind();
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Gridview1.RenderControl(htw);
var outputHtml = sw.ToString();
```

when i check the outputHtml it is an empty string. What i am doing wrong in this piece of code.

One thing to note is that gridview is lying inside a form with runat='server' tag and i have not overridden the VerifyRenderingInServerForm method.

Comment: Where in the Page Lifecycle are you executing this code?

Comment: i am doing this on postback, click event of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet is that you have set the visibility of the GridView to false. This will prevent the control from rendering, because well...it's invisible now. The result is an empty string.

If you don't want to show the GridView, just set the Visibility to true before you execute your rendering code and set it back afterwards:

```
    gv_sample.Visible = true;
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv_sample.RenderControl(htw);
    var outputHtml = sw.ToString();
    gv_sample.Visible = false;
```

You possibly will run into trouble with the RenderControl method now. If so, make sure you have set `EnableEventValidation="false"` in the Page directive and override the `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: If it still does not work for you, I will need some more code from your page and the .NET version you are using.